# Drawing a triangle in a coordinate plane given its three sides

Tags: math, html, graph, canvas, drawing

The length of three sides of the triangle, a, b and c will be given, and I need to find the coordinates of the vertices. The center (probably the circumcenter) can either be the origin or (x,y).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've read brainjam's answer and checked whether his answer is true and he is right.
Calculation:
O(0;0), A(a;0) and B(x;y) are the three points of the triangle. C1 is the circle around A and r1 = c; C2 is the circle around O and r2 = b. B(X;Y) is the intersection of C1 and C2, which means that the point is on both of the circles.

[image]

C1: (x - a) * (x - a) + y * y = c * c

C2: x * x + y * y = b * b

y * y = b * b - x * x

(x - a) * (x - a) + b * b - x * x = c * c

x * x - 2 * a * x + a * a + b * b - x * x - c * c = 0

2 * a * x = (a * a + b * b - c * c)

x = (a * a + b * b - c * c) / (2 * a)

y * y = b * b - ((a * a + b * b - c * c) / (2 * a)) * ((a * a + b * b - c * c) / (2 * a))

y = +- sqrt(b * b - ((a * a + b * b - c * c) / (2 * a)) * ((a * a + b * b - c * c) / (2 * a)))

Answer (score 8):

Place the first vertex at the origin (0,0).  Place the second vertex at (a,0).  To compute the third vertex, find the [intersection](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/2circle/) of the two circles with centers (0,0) and (a,0) and radii b and c.

**Update:** Lajos Arpad has given the details of computing the location of the third point in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001948/drawing-a-triangle-in-a-coordinate-plane-given-its-three-sides/4005449#4005449).  It boils down to (x,y) where x = (b<sup>2</sup>+a<sup>2</sup>-c<sup>2</sup>)/2a and y=±sqrt(b<sup>2</sup>-x<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Very good solution, I'll upvote you, but I find this answer incomplete, because you didn't write the details down. I took a sheet of paper and a pen and calculated what you've said, would like to share the result with anybody interested in the subject.

Comment: @Lajos, I'm not sure what needs to be proven.  The construction results in sides of length a,b,c ... I'd say this is obvious, why would you say this is not obvious?

Comment: Because a question was asked about this. I didn't know about this solution and I had to check. I'm an agnostic, believing only what I see. You were absolutely right with your post, I just wanted to specify it further. Also, the solution is a solution, because you can put the triangle anywhere you want using rotation and translation techniques.

Comment: @Lajos, I didn't mean that the construction was obvious, I meant that once you had it the lengths of the three sides were obvious.  Anyways, it was helpful of you to spell out the details of the third vertex, and I have linked to that.

Comment: "I meant that once you had it the lengths of the three sides were obvious." Sorry, I misunderstood at first. You're right.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

This question and the answers helped me out today in implementing this.  It will calculate the unknown vertices, "c" of circle intersections given 2 known points (a, b) and the distances (ac_length, bc_length) to the 3rd unknown vertex, "c".
Here is my resulting python implementation for anyone interested.

I also referenced the following:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadicalLine.html

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Using django's geos module for the `Point()` object, which could be replaced with shapely, or point objects removed altogether really.

```
from math import sqrt
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

class CirclesSeparate(BaseException):
    pass

class CircleContained(BaseException):
    pass

def discover_location(point_a, point_b, ac_length, bc_length):
    """
    Find point_c given:
        point_a
        point_b
        ac_length
        bc_length

    point_d == point at which the right-angle to c is formed.
    """
    ab_length = point_a.distance(point_b)    
    if ab_length > (ac_length + bc_length):
        raise CirclesSeparate("Given points do not intersect!")    
    elif ab_length < abs(ac_length - bc_length):
        raise CircleContained("The circle of the points do not intersect")    

    # get the length to the vertex of the right triangle formed,
    # by the intersection formed by circles a and b
    ad_length = (ab_length**2 + ac_length**2 - bc_length**2)/(2.0 * ab_length)    

    # get the height of the line at a right angle from a_length
    h  = sqrt(abs(ac_length**2 - ad_length**2))

    # Calculate the mid point (point_d), needed to calculate point_c(1|2)
    d_x = point_a.x + ad_length * (point_b.x - point_a.x)/ab_length
    d_y = point_a.y + ad_length * (point_b.y - point_a.y)/ab_length
    point_d = Point(d_x, d_y)    

    # get point_c location
    # --> get x
    c_x1 = point_d.x + h * (point_b.y - point_a.y)/ab_length
    c_x2 = point_d.x - h * (point_b.y - point_a.y)/ab_length

    # --> get y
    c_y1 = point_d.y - h * (point_b.x - point_a.x)/ab_length
    c_y2 = point_d.y + h * (point_b.x - point_a.x)/ab_length    

    point_c1 = Point(c_x1, c_y1)
    point_c2 = Point(c_x2, c_y2)    
    return point_c1, point_c2
```

Answer (score 3):

When drawing an unknown triangle, it's usually easiest to pick one side (say, the longest) and place it horizontally or vertically.  The endpoints of that side make up two of the triangle's vertices, and you can calculate the third by subdividing the triangle into two right triangles (the other two sides are the hypotenuses) and using the inverse sine/cosine functions to figure out the missing angles.  By subdividing into right triangles, I mean something that looks like the image here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Triangle.TrigArea.svg  Your first side would be AC in that drawing.

Once you have the triangle figured out, it should be easy to calculate it's center and translate it so that it is centered on whatever arbitrary center point you like.

Answer (score 2):

First check the that the triangle is possible:

```
    a+b >= c
    b+c >= a
    c+a >= b
```

Then, if it is, solve for the intersection of the two circles.  The basic vertices are

```
    {0,0}, {a,0}, {x,y}
```

where

```
    x = (a^2-b^2+c^2)/(2a)
    y = sqrt(c^2-x^2)
```

Finding the circumcenter is pretty easy from this point.

Comment: Where did you get the formula for `x` and `y`?

Comment: The formula is not correct (try it for a,b,c = 4,3,5 for example).  The correct formula is derived in the answer by Lajos.

Comment: @brainjam: x = (4^2 - 3^2 + 5^2)/(8) == 32/8 == 4 == a, as expected.  y = sqrt(5^2-16) = 3 == b, as expected.  It's a dressed up version of the law of cosines and then the Pythagorean theorem.  It also happens to be the *only* solution to the intersection of the two circles that *also* satisfies the triangle inequality for the side lengths (the three possibility tests I gave).

Comment: @Kshitij Parajul:  I made Mathematica solve for the intersection point, under the assumption of the triangle inequalities and positivity of a, b, c, x, and y.  However I recognized them as a tweaked law of cosines and Pythagoras' theorem and therefore understood how they would be derived and that they were correct.

Comment: you are absolutely right.  I was associating the radius b (instead of c) with the center (0,0), so was expecting the answer (0,3) instead of (4,3).